# How do I update this openGL code from cocos2d v1 to v2.0?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

This is the code Im updating.  it works fine on cocos2d v1.0 but fails on 2.0:

```
-(void) drawGuy {
    glLineWidth(4.0f);

    ccPointSize(16);

    //Enable line smoothing
    //glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);

    //Draw a blue quadratic bezier curve
    ccDrawColor4B(0, 0, 255, 255);
    ccDrawQuadBezier(ccp(100,0), ccp(240,70), ccp(380,0), 10);

    //Draw a hollow purple circle
    ccDrawColor4B(255, 0, 255, 255);
    ccDrawCircle(ccp(240,160), 125.0f, 0.0f, 100, NO);

    //Draw a solid red lines
    ccDrawColor4B(255, 0, 0, 255);
    ccDrawLine(ccp(170,220), ccp(220,190));
    ccDrawLine(ccp(260,190), ccp(310,220));

    //Draw a green point
    ccDrawColor4B(0, 255, 0, 255);
    ccDrawPoint(ccp(200,180));
    ccDrawPoint(ccp(280,180));

    //Draw a turquoise solid circle
    ccDrawColor4B(0, 128, 255, 50);
    ccDrawSolidCircle(ccp(200,180), 25.0f, 0.0f, 20, NO);
    ccDrawSolidCircle(ccp(280,180), 25.0f, 0.0f, 20, NO);

    //Draw a brown hollow circle
    ccDrawColor4B(64,32, 0, 255);
    ccDrawCircle(ccp(200,180), 25.0f, 0.0f, 100, NO);
    ccDrawCircle(ccp(280,180), 25.0f, 0.0f, 100, NO);

    //Draw brown lines
    ccDrawColor4B(64,32, 0, 255);
    ccDrawLine(ccp(225,180), ccp(255,180));
    ccDrawLine(ccp(305,180), ccp(370,160));
    ccDrawLine(ccp(175,180), ccp(110,160));

    //Draw an orange polygon
    ccDrawColor4B(255, 128, 0, 255);
    CGPoint vertices[5]={ ccp(230,150),ccp(240,160),ccp(250,150),ccp(245,140),ccp(235,140) };
    ccDrawPoly(vertices, 5, YES);

    //Draw a yellow cubic bezier curve
    ccDrawColor4B(255, 255, 0, 255);
    ccDrawCubicBezier(ccp(170,90), ccp(220,150), ccp(260,50), ccp(320,100), 10);

    //Restore original values
    glLineWidth(1);
    //glDisable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    ccDrawColor4B(255,255,255,255);
    ccPointSize(1);
}
```

[image: My openGL Fails]

Comment: That's nice to hear. Would you be able to share with us the exact nature of this failure. Is the device running 2.0 turned on, have you connected it to your computer, have you discombobulated the warp phase inhibitors?... the point i'm trying to make is we need some more context if we are going to help you.

Comment: Sure @Bergasms This code should draw a picture of a head with eyes and glasses.  The problem is that it fails to draw correctly.  Specifically, his eyes.  Ill update the question with the appropriate pic